# straight from host-mkpasswd to generating root file system

Tags: makefile, buildroot

I appear to have dug my self a reasonably deep hole and am hoping for some help before resorting to a fresh clone and then manually copying in files.

When I attempt to build things look pretty normal as all the host utilities are built then the make process skips all of the target packages and attempts to generate the root file system:

> >>> host-mkpasswd buildroot-2015.11.1 Installing to host directory
>   /usr/bin/install -D -m 755 /data/Build/buildroot/output/build/host-mkpasswd-buildroot-2015.11.1/mkpasswd
>   /data/Build/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/mkpasswd
>   >>>   Generating root filesystem image rootfs.ext2

Does anyone have any ideas on where to look into this problem?

Comment: This does not sound like a programming question -- maybe you can get better help on superuser.com or serverfault.com?

Comment: Where exactly buildroot stuff falls in the programming/sys admin divide is tough. But happy to take it there if that is the consensus. But neither of those have a buildroot tag....

Comment: I don't see where you see a problem in your report. Yes, Buildroot builds everything it has to build, and the build ends by building the host-mkpasswd package, and finally generating the root filesystem image. This looks perfectly fine. Is your problem the "make process skips all of the target packages" ?

Comment: Yeah, I have target packages selected, none of them get built